# About Isomorphism of Quotient Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra

Are $R[x]/(x^2)$ and $R[x]/((x-1)^2)$ isomorphic? How to do such question in general? I really don't know where to start, prove or disprove.

Answer (score 1):

Start by showing that $f(x) \mapsto f(x-1)$ is an isomorphism of $R[x]$

Then $f(x) \mapsto f(x-1) + ((x-2)^2)$ is an epimorphism from $R[x]$ to $R[x]/((x-1)^2)$.

Finally, determine the kernel of this empimorphism to get the isomorphism you seek.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you see that both rings have nilpotent elements, both are $2$-dimensional vectorial spaces over $\mathbb{R}$ so  they could be isomorphic. In order to show this properly you should consider a surjective ring morphism from $\mathbb{R}[x]$ to $\mathbb{R}[x]/((x-1)^2)$ whose kernel is the ideal $(x^2)$ (then by factorization property you get your isomorphism). Now I let you show that :

$$\phi:\mathbb{R}[x]\mapsto  \mathbb{R}[x]/((x-1)^2)$$

$$\phi(P(x)):=P(x-1) \text{ mod } ((x-1)^2)$$

does the job.